# Can we prepare any ICs similar to decoder or demux , but for selecting multiple pins simultaneously?

Tags: arduino, digital-logic, circuit-design, robotics

It is possible to select the output pins sequentially using decoder or demux. But for selecting more than 2 output pins at same time, they don't work as the decoder /demux are single output selector ICs. Can someone suggest as to how to select more than 2 outputs simultaneously?[image: The image is for selecting power to the 8 outputs, How to select H1,H3,H6 simultaneously?] And the factor of limitation being that it should be compatible with Arduino or similar Microcontrollers.

Comment: Sorry, we need way more context. What system becomes unstable? What does system stability have to do with demuxing/muxing? Really, describe your whole picture.

Comment: Dear Shuv_T. I suggest you tell us in details what you have now and why it does not work. Please provide schematics and/or diagrams. Your remark about *"the system becomes unstable. "* is very vague and makes me suspect you may be looking for a wrong solution to your problem (Look up "XY problem").

Comment: Wire decoders/multiplexers in parallel, one for each wire.

Comment: @Andyaka If we increase the no, of outputs to be switched to 9 or 10 at the same time, parallel connection might get messy.

Comment: Yes, it might get messy unless you design it to be unmessy. If something can't be simple then, by definition it is complex but that does not have to = messy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [I/O Expander](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tca6424a.pdf).

There you can control behaviour of individual pins or multiple pins in a batch.

It is produced in different packaging for any application.

Answer (score 0):

Forget about using a decoder at all. Simply drive the enables directly from pins on your MCU. Then you can select any combination, including more than two at a time if necessary.

Note that to select an arbitrary combination of 0, 1 or 2 outputs, you need a total of 8 output pins from your MCU anyway (3 select bits and an enable bit for each of two decoders), so you might as well use the same 8 bits to directly control the enables.